# Replace character in string with Uppercase of next in line (Pascal Casing)

Tags: c#, string, replace, replacewith

I want to remove all underscores from a string with the uppercase of the character following the underscore. So for example: `_my_string_` becomes: `MyString` similarly: `my_string` becomes `MyString`

Is there a simpler way to do it? I currently have the following (assuming no input has two consecutive underscores):

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] == '_')
                sb.Append(char.ToUpper(input[++i]));
            else if (i == 0)
                sb.Append(char.ToUpper(input[i]));
            else
                sb.Append(input[i]);
        }
        if (i < input.Length && input[i] != '_')
            sb.Append(input[i]);

        return sb.ToString();
```

Now I know this is not totally related, but I thought to run some numbers on the implementations provided in the answers, and here are the results in Milliseconds for each implementation using `1000000 iterations` of the string: `"_my_string_121_a_"` :

```
Achilles: 313
Raj: 870
Damian: 7916
Dmitry: 5380
Equalsk: 574
```

method utilised:

```
        Stopwatch stp = new Stopwatch();
        stp.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            sb = Test("_my_string_121_a_");
        }
        stp.Stop();
        long timeConsumed= stp.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

In the end I think I'll go with Raj's implementation, because it's just very simple and easy to understand.

Comment: Presumably this falls over currently, as `_my_string_` makes you look for the char after the last `_`

Comment: No it does not. I'm looping till Length-1.

Comment: My bad, didn't spot that :P

Comment: @Achilles let me know if my solution works for you or not.. If its not what you asked for I can delete it at-least. There are some newbies who never understood the question but complain on the logic..

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Seems to work for me. I'm testing it out.

Comment: @Achilles thanks.. Also do you have any intention of handling white space? If so do you want to capitalize the first character after the space?

Comment: No intention of handling whitespaces. I'm basically converting variable names from database... I don't think whitespaces are allowed in variable names there.

Comment: @Achilles thanks for the clarification..

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre does the OP comment clear your doubts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This must do it using [**ToTitleCase**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx) using `System.Globalization` namespace

```
static string toCamel(string input)
{        
    TextInfo info = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
    input= info.ToTitleCase(input).Replace("_", string.Empty);
    return input;
}
```

[image]

Comment: But that's not the question, if the string was "hello_mynameis_john", the result would be "helloMynameisJohn"

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre `_my_string_ becomes: MyString` is the expected result. and the above code does it

Comment: Right, but it doesn't do the actual functionality that is asked for. That is like me saying I wan't to remove the fifth character in ***any*** string, and presenting you with `string input = "1234 678";`, then you supplying me with the code `input.Replace(" ", "");`

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre do you know if the OP can have multiple words together? I don't see OP saying that..

Comment: No, but I clearly see this, which suggests the very same. "*I want to remove all underscores from a string with the uppercase of the character following the underscore.*"

Comment: **with the uppercase of the character following the underscore** he didnt mention Uppercase within the string.. He wants uppercase just after the underscore @AlfieGoodacre

Comment: If I gave you the string "hello my name is_john", what happens?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre you get `HelloMyNameIsJohn` Tested it.. Also why are you going out of the question context.. why are there `spaces` between the words? That is not what OP has.. If you are looking for solution which works magically on all kind of inputs then this is not that solution..

Comment: Because the code will not only be used in the question's context. the result of that should be "hello my name isJohn", as such your answer is not the correct one.

Comment: `Because the code will not only be used in the question's context` how is that going to relate my answer? I gave my answer to the question posted..     As far as this question is considered this answer gives him the expected output..

Comment: This seems like a lost cause

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre You comments or claims of saying the logic doesn't work is totally random.. You are coming up with different inputs and expect this code to work for you.. But I have posted the solution for the OP.. If you need something more magical Please ask a new question..

Comment: I don't need anything at all, I can write code just fine and the OP already had, you have provided a patchwork solution though as opposed to a solid one

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre problem is you never understood the question `I want to remove all underscores from a string with the uppercase of the character following the underscore` pay attention to **uppercase of the character following the underscore**.. If you still don't understand it.. I cant help it brother..

Comment: I am not saying your solution is 100% wrong, but it is not correct, as it is very fragile and will not work in 99% of situations aside from the given one

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre when you know that the input string contains `_` and you need to make the character after it as `captial` what else condition will break this code ? Can you please give me a test string.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre `anything with space` is not in the context of the problem.. Your input itself is wrong.

Comment: All other solutions work with spaces though, so yours, as I stated, is fragile. That is all I am saying, I am not going to reply any further because this is just a cyclic argument of you not understanding a word of what I am saying

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre lol what are you talking mate.. if other logic's handle `spaces` why should my logic handle it too? What if the OP doesnt want to handle a `space` do you even know?? you never know.. I won't be surprised if you comment next saying "`$` is not removed and code doesnt work"... I pity the way you never understood the question.  Please understand the question before accusing the logic is fragile..

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre please check the comments by the OP.  Your understanding on the question is 100% wrong. The problem with you as I might guess is that English might not be your first language, But that's ok .. It was nice talking to you..

Comment: Well that's awfully condescending, as it is my first language, the OP has changed the criteria about 3 times now, so the question is different to how it originally was. Aside from that, you also changed it to not affect spaces, so you proved me right anyway

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre problem is that you are not experienced enough to understand a given problem. you need to always think of "why" something is asked and not jump into "how" to do it... Happy coding!!

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre take it positively.. I am just trying to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Shorter (*regular expressions*), but I doubt if it's better (regular expressions are less readable):

```
  string source = "_my_string_123__A_";

  // MyString123A  
  string result = Regex
     // _ + lower case Letter -> upper case letter (thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew)
    .Replace(source, @"(_+|^)(\p{Ll})?", match => match.Groups[2].Value.ToUpper())
     // all the other _ should be just removed
    .Replace("_", "");
```

Comment: Why do you use an optional group? Why not match a lowercase letter and capture it into Group 1? Also, short regex patterns are quite readable.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: I have to remove *all* the underscopes whether they're followed by letter or not (e.g. tail one)

Comment: I believe you can still enhance it like `@"_+(.)"` and pass `source.TrimEnd('_')` to the regex.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: thank you for the improvement! I think `.Replace("_", "")` after the regular expression will do both `_12` case and tail `_`

Comment: doesn't work for my_string : returns myString, Expected: MyString

Comment: @Achilles: it was expected behaviour for the `toCamel`; for the `toTitle` you have to change the implementation a bit (see my edit) since you've change the question. See my edit

Answer (score 3):

Loops over each character and converts to uppercase as necessary.

```
public string GetNewString(string input)
{
    var convert = false;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var c in input)
    {
        if (c == '_')
        {
            convert = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (convert)
        {
            sb.Append(char.ToUpper(c));
            convert = false;
            continue;
        }

        sb.Append(c);
    }

    return sb.ToString().First().ToString().ToUpper() + sb.ToString().Substring(1);
}
```

Usage:

```
GetNewString("my_string");
GetNewString("___this_is_anewstring_");
GetNewString("___this_is_123new34tring_");
```

Output:

> MyString
>   ThisIsAnewstring
>   ThisIs123new34tring

Answer (score 2):

Try with Regex:

```
var regex = new Regex("^[a-z]|_[a-z]?");
var result = regex.Replace("my_string_1234", x => x.Value== "_" ? "" : x.Value.Last().ToString().ToUpper());
```

Tested with:

```
my_string   -> MyString
_my_string  -> MyString
_my_string_ -> MyString
```

Comment: What if `"_my_123_"` input has been provided?

Comment: _my_123_ will become My123

Comment: doesn't work for my_string : returns myString, Expected: MyString

Comment: @Achilles wait so the first character should always be capitalised?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Yes, not exactly camel case ... I see where the confusion comes from.

Comment: @Achilles this wasn't specified in the question, you might want to edit that in, as these answers solve the issue outlined in your question but not the issue you actually have

Comment: @Achilles I have fixed that for my_string

Answer (score 1):

You need convert snake case to camel case, You can use this code it's working for me

```
  var x ="_my_string_".Split(new[] {"_"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(s => char.ToUpperInvariant(s[0]) + s.Substring(1, s.Length - 1))
                .Aggregate(string.Empty, (s1, s2) => s1 + s2);
```

x = MyString

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    static string toCamel(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((i == 0) || (i > 0 && input[i - 1] == '_'))
                sb.Append(char.ToUpper(input[i]));
            else
                sb.Append(char.ToLower(input[i]));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```